# In Scala, What is correct way to filter Spark Cassandra RDD by a List[String]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a list of ids in string format, this list can be roughly 20,000 ids long:

```
var timelineIds = source.map(a => a.timelineid);
timelineIds = timelineIds.distinct.cache; // disticnt list we need this for later
var timelineIdsString = timelineIds.map(a => a.asInstanceOf[String]).collect.toList;
```

When I use this list against one of my cassandra tables it works just fine, no matter the size of timelineIdsString:

```
var timelineHistorySource = sc.cassandraTable[Timeline]("acd", "timeline_history_bytimelineid")
        .select("ownerid", "userid", "timelineid", "timelinetype", "starttime", "endtime", "attributes", "states")
if (constrain)
    timelineHistorySource = timelineHistorySource.where("timelineid IN ?", timelineIdsString)
```

When I do it against another of my tables, it never completes when I have over 1000 ids in the List:

```
var dispositionSource = sc.cassandraTable[DispositionSource]("acd","dispositions_bytimelineid")
            .select("ownerid","dispositionid","month","timelineid","createddate","createduserid")
if(constrain)
    dispositionSource = dispositionSource.where("timelineid IN ?", timelineIdsString);
```

Both cassandra tables have the key as the timelineid so I know that its correct. This code works fine as long as timelineids is a small list.

Is there a better way to filter from cassandra RDD? Is it the size of the IN clause causing it to choke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of performing join on Spark level it's better to perform join using Cassandra itself - in this case you'll read from Cassandra only the necessary data (given that join key is partition or primary key).  For RDDs this is could be done with `.joinWithCassandraTable` function ([doc](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#performing-efficient-joins-with-cassandra-tables-since-12)):

```scala
import com.datastax.spark.connector._

val toJoin = sc.parallelize(1 until 5).map(x => Tuple1(x.toInt))
val joined = toJoin.joinWithCassandraTable("test", "jtest1")
  .on(SomeColumns("pk"))

scala> joined.toDebugString
res21: String =
(8) CassandraJoinRDD[150] at RDD at CassandraRDD.scala:18 []
 |  ParallelCollectionRDD[147] at parallelize at <console>:33 []
```

For Dataframes it's so called [direct join](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md#direct-join) that is available since SCC 2.5 (see [announcement](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2020/05/advanced-apache-cassandra-analytics-now-open-all)) - you need to pass some configs to enable it, see docs:

```scala
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._

val cassdata = spark.read.cassandraFormat("jtest1", "test").load

val toJoin = spark.range(1, 5).select($"id".cast("int").as("id"))
val joined = toJoin.join(cassdata, cassdata("pk") === toJoin("id"))

scala> joined.explain
== Physical Plan ==
Cassandra Direct Join [pk = id#2] test.jtest1 - Reading (pk, c1, c2, v) Pushed {}
+- *(1) Project [cast(id#0L as int) AS id#2]
   +- *(1) Range (1, 5, step=1, splits=8)
```

I have quite a [long & detailed blog post about joins with Cassandra](https://alexott.blogspot.com/2020/07/spark-effective-joins-with-cassandra.html) - check it for more details.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.  Its a solid answer on the best way to join RDD efficiently and quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try instead keeping the IDs list as a dataframe, `timelineIds`, and inner joining the table with it based on `timelineid`. Then remove the unnecessary column (`timelineIds.timelineid`) from the resulting df.

Comment: Thats essentially what I went to and it work pretty well.  Just not sure if that is the preferred filtering method.  
'''
var dispositionsFromSQL = sparksession.sql(
   """
   |SELECT 
   |cr.ownerid, cr.dispositionid, cr.month, cr.sessionid, cr.createddate, cr.createduserid, cr.channeltype, cr.queuename
   |FROM allDisps cr 
   |INNER JOIN allTimelineIds dn ON cr.sessionid = dn.timelineid 
   """.stripMargin
  )
  .toDF();
'''

Comment: This kind of join will be performed on the Spark level, and that is inefficient for big data sets. It's better to use direct join instead